# Disable HTTPS on AWS S3 using Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use the Java API for S3 (getting an object) with plain HTTP (instead of HTTPS), but can't find the parameters to do so.

Currently I'm using a REST client to call http://s3.amazonaws.com instead of https://s3.amazonaws.com

Java API I am using:

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = amazonS3.getObject(getS3BotBucket(), resourceFile).getObjectContent();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get an instance of the client builder with `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()`.

Call `withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration.withProtocol(Protocol.HTTP))` on the client builder instance, then call the builder's `build` method to get your S3 client instance that will use http instead of https

Comment: it needs to be `withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withProtocol(Protocol.HTTP))` since withProtocol is an instance method

Comment: How can we do this with AWS S3 Java SDK 2.0 please?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your GET request does not use the SSL endpoint, you can specify the bucket for the request by using the HTTP Host header. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingSpecifyBuckety

Comment: But I still have to use a REST client. I want to use the S3 Java SDK